# Div display in odd way

Tags: html, css

I have an authentication panel that looks as follow:

[image]

As you can see the red box is displayed to small.

The code behind the source:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="message">
        <h2 class="title">AUTHENTICATION</h2>
        <p class="info">Please sign in with username and password.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="ui red message error">Wrong username or password.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sign-in">
        <form class="ui form">

            <div class="field ui big left icon input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                <i class="user icon"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="field ui big left icon input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <i class="lock icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="fluid ui blue button">Sign In</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.message {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    background: #bbd0e6;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.message, h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.message, .info {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.message, .error {

}

.sign-in {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 15%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

I tried to set the width of the red box to

```
.message, .error {
    width: 80%;
}
```

After it changes to:

[image]

It seems to be, that the width of the red box is proportional to whole screen not to the *AUTHENTICATION* box.

How can I determine the width to be proportional to the *AUTHENTICATION* box?

Comment: Looks like you only want `.error` to be `80%` - not `message`as well.

Comment: but `.message` is set to `20%` only.

Comment: Yes, but the `.error` is inside the `message`.

Comment: @nelek `20%` to the whole screen.

Comment: yes, so `.error` will be 20% of `.message`

Comment: @nelek how can I set `.error` `80%` to `.message`?

Comment: there is fiddle and work ok ... https://jsfiddle.net/38msuxd3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

`.message > error {
     width: 80%;
}`

When you use `,` when assigning a style in CSS, you're telling the browser to assign that style to a list of things. Example from your code:

```
.message {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    background: #bbd0e6;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.message, h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.message, .info {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

That snip defines `.message`, then redefines it two more times, while also defining `h2` and `.info`. I assume in all cases you're actually trying to get at the children of `.message` (but I could be wrong). Follow the link for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: @zero_coding I edited to add some explanation of what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with:

```
.message {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    background: #bbd0e6;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.message > h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.message > .info {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.message > .error {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Thanks everyone.